# Password Protected Wordpress Page Unwanted Redirect

Tags: wordpress, redirect, password-protection

Problem: unable to access Protected pages using standard WP protection

Expected Behavior: Enter page password. Page refreshes to show protected content.
What happens instead, is the page redirects to the homepage

NOTE: We have duplicated this site on a local server and a staging WP engine server, but the problem described does not occur there.
Also, tried disabling all plugins and changed to default theme. Redirect to homepage after protected page login attempt still occurs.

It seems to be server specific, only happens on one server but not others and works as expected.